# How to center multiple <figure> elements in one row?

Tags: html, css, element, centering, figure

Hello stack overflow members,

I have a similar question like discussed within the question "How to center multiple inline-block elements with CSS?". Unfortunately the provided answers didn't help me, that's why I had to create a new question.

I use 4  elements with fixed width and I would like to center them in one row.
The text-align:center styling has no effect on the "div".

```html
<style>
.figurestyle {
  width:160px;
  padding-left:5px; 
  padding-right:5px;  
  margin-left:0px; 
  margin-right:0px;
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>

<div style="text-align:center;">
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img1.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text1</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img2.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text2</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img3.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text3</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img4.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text4</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the answer?
Many thanks in advance

cheers 
Bas

Comment: why don't you use `display:flex;`?

Comment: it's working fine, everything is aligned

Comment: Thanks a lot,

I found out finally that my provided code is indeed CORRECT (and the provided answers here of course also)! The reason why it didn't work, is probably because of another code which I didn't provide in my example. I work with a CMS and the editor of that system applies a class additionally to the images. I don't know exactly what that class does (as I am not the developer of the CMS), but when I remove that class, then this HTML code works correctly. That's why I assume, that something from that class overruled some settings of this code, or is in "conflict" with this code.

Comment: Alright, it's okay!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few days ago, in fact, and solved by using `display: flex;`. Like so:

```
<style>
.figurestyle {
  width:160px;
  padding-left:5px; 
  padding-right:5px;  
  margin-left:0px; 
  margin-right:0px;
}

.parentFigureStyle {

    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

</style>

<div class="parentFigureStyle">
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img1.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text1</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img2.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text2</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img3.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text3</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figurestyle"><img src="img4.jpg">
<figcaption style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">Text4</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

In general, you should just make the parent `<div>` have a `display: flex;` and make it in a row, and justify the content to the center. This should work.

Comment: Thanks Jason,
your code works indeed too. But from the "responsiveness" point of view I go for the first solution above. In that case, when the window gets smaller, the pictures are going to be placed in the next row.
At your solution, all 4 pictures stay in the same row, and you receive a navigation bar under the pictures when the window gets smaller. This is also fine, I just prefer the other solution.

Comment: Yep, actually that's where I'm heading with my flex... I'll just use the code from the question above to have a second line on smaller resolutions. Great job!